# Can't get rid of white space at top of page

Tags: html, css, whitespace, space

I cannot figure out why the white space at the top of the page won't go away.  I have a reset, and I can't see any padding/margins that would effect the top.

Because I don't want to enter excessive code and give you the wrong thing to work with, the link is live and the code can be viewed from there.

Here it is: http://www.lymemd.org/indexmm6.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I view your source code, right after the  tag, there is `" "`.   When I delete this in the inspector, this removes the space at the top.

Check your code to see what it causing this bad element at the top of the page.  I *assume* it doesn't belong there at all... maybe a typo?

[image]

Comment: Is that in the HTML or the CSS?  I can't find the quotations?  After what tag?  Sorry and thank you!

Comment: In your HTML.   I've attached a screenshot to show you where the quotes show up in your source code.   The area highlighted in the box above is causing the space at the top of your page.

Comment: You might want to make sure there is no spacing between your `<body>` tag and your `<div id="Header">` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `<!DOCTYPE>` to the very start of your HTML document. It doesn't belong inside the `body`.